# how to count two similiar Sql select and add together?

Tags: sql

I have two query and I want to add their result together.
Basically i want to count all occurrences then add those ones to it where it has a connection with another table. So if it appears in the other table 2 times the final count value for the notRelevantId should be 3.

```
SELECT table1.notRelevantId, COUNT(0) as numberOfOccurrences
FROM table1
WHERE Deleted = 0 (AND other filters)
GROUP BY table1.notRelevantId

SELECT table1.notRelevantId, COUNT(0) as numberOfOccurrences
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.connectionId = table2.connectionId
WHERE Deleted = 0 (AND other filters) AND table2.connectionId is not null
GROUP BY table1.notRelevantId
```

1. query result

| notRelevantId | numberOfOccurrences |
| --- | --- |
| 464 | 15 |
| 536 | 1 |
| 528 | 358 |
| 465 | 254 |

2. query result

| notRelevantId | numberOfOccurrences |
| --- | --- |
| 464 | 14 |
| 528 | 352 |
| 465 | 166 |

Expected result:

| notRelevantId | numberOfOccurrences |
| --- | --- |
| 464 | 29 |
| 536 | 1 |
| 528 | 710 |
| 465 | 420 |

Comment: `AND table2.connectionId is not null` is redundant. the column's usage in the JOIN condition implies it's not null.

Answer (score 2):

`UNION ALL` to put them together, then `SUM` by `notRelevantId`

```
SELECT notRelevantId, SUM(numberOfOccurrences) AS numberOfOccurrences
FROM (
SELECT table1.notRelevantId, COUNT(*) as numberOfOccurrences
FROM table1
WHERE Deleted = 0 (AND other filters)
GROUP BY table1.notRelevantId
UNION ALL 
SELECT table1.notRelevantId, COUNT(*) as numberOfOccurrences
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.connectionId = table2.connectionId
WHERE Deleted = 0 (AND other filters) AND table2.connectionId is not null
GROUP BY table1.notRelevantId
)
GROUP BY notRelevantId;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are cleaner (easier to read) ways to write this but...

```
SELECT 
    NoConnect.NotRelevantID
    ,NoConnect.nubmerOfOccurrences + WithConnect.numberOfOccurrences AS [countOccurrences]
FROM 
    (
        SELECT table1.notRelevantId, COUNT(0) as numberOfOccurrences
        FROM table1
        WHERE Deleted = 0 (AND other filters)
        GROUP BY table1.notRelevantId
    ) AS NoConnect
  JOIN
    (
        SELECT table1.notRelevantId, COUNT(0) as numberOfOccurrences
        FROM table1
          INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.connectionId = table2.connectionId
        WHERE Deleted = 0 (AND other filters) AND table2.connectionId is not null
        GROUP BY table1.notRelevantId
    ) AS WithConnect ON WithConnect.NotRelevantID = NoConnect.NotRelevantID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use this query. Otherwise you can use `UNION` and `SUM`

```
SELECT 
    A.notRelevantId,SUM(numberOfOccurrences) 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        table1.notRelevantId, COUNT(0) as numberOfOccurrences
    FROM table1
    WHERE Deleted = 0 --(AND other filters)
    GROUP BY table1.notRelevantId 
    ) A full outer join 
    (SELECT 
        table1.notRelevantId, COUNT(0) as numberOfOccurrences
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.connectionId = table2.connectionId
    WHERE Deleted = 0 -- (AND other filters) 
    AND table2.connectionId is not null
    GROUP BY table1.notRelevantId ) B 
on A.notRelevantId = B.notRelevantId
    GROUP BY A.notRelevantId
```

Comment: That ancient OUTER JOIN syntax isn't supported by more than Oracle I think. And it has been deprecated for many years.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @jarlh : update the query, removed the ancient outer join :P